# BLTouch Deploying then immediately retracting while homing

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-cr-10, bltouch

I just bought a Creality CR10 Max (this is my 9th printer, 3 of my others are creality and they all have a BLTouch installed).

I have only made probably 5 prints on this machine since I bought it but started having probing failures after the 3rd. So i decided to replace the BLTouch to get a consistent experience. After replacing the probe with another Genuine BLTouch when homing, the printer would perform X and Y without any problems then go to bed center to home Z. The probe would deploy and immediately retract then the printer would would move up on z a small way then deploy the probe, immediately retract then move up on z again before declaring a probe failure and stopping. Thinking I was having an issue with the new probe I replaced it with a clone BLTouch that performed the same way then again with a second clone that had identical behavior. That's 4 probes all with the same behavior. I could use a BLTouch guru to let me know what that failure type means and how I should troubleshoot from here. I just spend $1000 on a printer and it's a paperweight.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Please check the connections of the cable boom to the board

Comment: I have checked the wiring closely and there are no visual problems that I can see.